# Could a bluetooth, speaker and microphone equiped arduino be used to form a range sensing swarm?

Tags: sensors, bluetooth

I am trying to figure out how to build a system of devices that could, on command, notify similar devices that are within a configurable distance. Maximum ranges would need to be around 20' though up to 40' would be preferable. Accuracy +- 20% is acceptable as is degradation due to things such as large intervening objects, walls, buildings etc. Only one notification is expected in any given 10 second block.

I was thinking the sending device could send a ultrasonic ping, and then send a data packet with the ping time stamp and range notification to all devices in range. And then each receiver could compare the ping receive time and range notification and calculate if it is within the range given in the data packet.

Would this work? Is there a better way to do this?